# getting value of object in class

Tags: php, oop, scope

i am using MVC pattern and i  have a class Database, there is database connection, now in my controller i want to do a query.

This is my controller

require_once 'application/models/Database.php';

```
class IndexController extends Controller {
    public function indexAction() {
        $query = $database->selectQuery("SELECT * FROM students");
        $this->view->render('index','template');
    }
}
```

I need to pass $database(object of Database class) to $this->database. I cant use __construct function to define the value there, because there is no creation of IndexController class. So the question is how i can pass the database object to my controller and use it there?

Thanks

Comment: NEVER do queries in your controller. It defeats the purpose of the MVC pattern. Do queries in your Model and call those methods from your controller.

Comment: " I cant use __construct function to define the value there, because there is no creation of IndexController class" huh?

Comment: @PeeHaa couldn't it be that some framework or other class, etc, is in control of that (a generic process) and can't be manipulated?

Comment: It could be the case, but considering OP didn't make any mention of it in his question nor in his tags who knows.

Comment: Justin Woods, NEVER? What are you talking about. I have looked in Symfony, the query is in controller!

Comment: Doing queries in controller is right way (as in symfony). And when im trying to pass $database to method it tells missing argument.

Comment: @user3005741 DB queries in the controller? Bahahaha.

Comment: @user3005741 I hate to break it to you, but even Symfony breaks the rules in some places.

Comment: $product = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')
        ->find($id);

Comment: Could you tell me then what is this?

Comment: $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT p FROM AcmeStoreBundle:Product p WHERE p.price > :price ORDER BY p.price ASC'
)->setParameter('price', '19.99');

$products = $query->getResult();

Comment: @user3005741 please, start by reading what are the responsibilities for each part of MVC triade: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_view_controller#Component_interactions